# How can I obtain the Full Name of the currently logged in user via Terminal when run as root?

Tags: terminal, bash

This command works great to list the Full Name out:

```
finger $(whoami) | egrep -o 'Name: [a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,}' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | xargs echo
```

But, if you run it after a

```
sudo su
```

It returns CVMS Root System Administrator

I'm wondering if there's perhaps another place to read the Full Name variable? Is there a User object somewhere that would list this out? I thought I was on to something with

```
dscacheutil -q user | grep -A 3 -B 2 -e uid:\ 5'[0-9][0-9]'
```

But it doesn't look like Full Name is represented in that return data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed a two-line approach:

```
username="$(stat -f%Su /dev/console)"
realname="$(dscl . -read /Users/$username RealName | cut -d: -f2 | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | grep -v "^$")"
```

And then you can just echo out the realname variable.

Comment: I did, but when I was working on this your edits probably weren't up yet, because I couldn't get your answer to work "out of the box." My answer is what I ended up actually implementing, so I know it works for my purposes. My original comment on your answer was "Thanks! Got me close enough that I figured it out from there!" which I stand by, since it did indeed give me the brain jumpstart I needed, so thank you very much for getting me on the right track :)

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `id -P $(stat -f%Su /dev/console) | awk -F '[:]' '{print $8}'`

`id -P $(stat -f%Su /dev/console)` yields:

```
adminuser:********:501:20::0:0:AdminUser:/Users/adminuser:/bin/bash
```

`awk -F '[:]' '{print $8}'` yields the 8th term (the "RealName") of an output separated by colons.

As proposed by [fd0](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/128657/fd0) you can alternatively use:

```
id -P $(stat -f%Su /dev/console) | cut -d : -f 8
```

which is even more simple/elegant.

Comment: +1 for `id -P` though I would use `cut` instead of `awk` on the straight forward string.

Comment: @fd0 Added as an alternative proposal. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use dscl to read the RealName:

```
$ dscl . -read /Users/grgarside RealName
RealName:
 George Garside
```

The following will give you just what you're after. This uses ‘who am i’ to get the username, then sed to format the output.

```
$ dscl . -read "/Users/$(who am i | awk '{print $1}')" RealName | sed -n 's/^ //g;2p'
George Garside
```

Comment: I have added my own answer as well based on this. The edited command here does not help as whoami does not return the correct data when run as root.

Comment: @Joodoo My answer uses ‘who am i’, not ‘whoami’. The former returns the correct username which is why I used it.

Comment: Anything wrong with $HOME? as in `dscl . -read $HOME RealName | awk 'NR == 2`

Comment: @Darren $HOME changes after `sudo su` to root’s home so it’s unsuitable for this question.

Comment: @grg Fair. Found what I needed, so thanks all